# Running a long operation within an event handler

Tags: acumatica

I need to run some address validation on Customer Location addresses using a 3rd party API to determine if the address is residential or commercial. This validation should run whenever an address field is changed. In other words, the validation should be run in the `Address_RowUpdated` event handler.

Because the function is calling a 3rd party API, I believe that it should be done in a separate thread, using `PXLongOperation` so that it does not hold up address saving and fails gracefully if the API is unavailable or returns an error.

However, I am not sure if the architecture of running a long operation within an event handler is supported or if a different approach would be better.

Here is my code.

```
public class CustomerLocationMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerLocationMaint>
{
    protected virtual void Address_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        PX.Objects.CR.Address row = (PX.Objects.CR.Address)e.Row;
        if (row != null)
        {
            Location location = this.Base.Location.Current;
            PXCache locationCache = Base.LocationCurrent.Cache;

            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate
            {
                RunCheckResidential(location, locationCache); 
            });

            this.Base.LocationCurrent.Cache.IsDirty = true; 
        }
    }

    protected void RunCheckResidential(Location location, PXCache locationCache)
    {
        string messages = "";

        PX.Objects.CR.Address defAddress = PXSelect<PX.Objects.CR.Address,
            Where<PX.Objects.CR.Address.addressID, Equal<Required<Location.defAddressID>>>>.Select(Base, location.DefAddressID);

        FValidator validator = new FValidator();
        AddressValidationReply reply = validator.Validate(defAddress);
        AddressValidationResult result = reply.AddressResults[0];

        bool isResidential = location.CResedential ?? false; 
        if (result.Classification == FClassificationType.RESIDENTIAL) 
        {
            isResidential = true;
        } else if (result.Classification == FClassificationType.BUSINESS)
        {
            isResidential = false;
        } else
        {
            messages += "Residential classification is: " + result.Classification + "\r\n";
        }
        location.CResedential = isResidential;

        locationCache.Update(location);
        Base.LocationCurrent.Update(location);
        Base.Actions.PressSave();

        // Display relevant messages
        if (reply.HighestSeverity == NotificationSeverityType.SUCCESS)
            String addressCorrection = validator.AddressCompare(result.EffectiveAddress, defAddress);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(addressCorrection))
                messages += addressCorrection;
        }

        PXSetPropertyException message = new PXSetPropertyException(messages, PXErrorLevel.Warning);
        PXLongOperation.SetCustomInfo(new LocationMessageDisplay(message));
        //throw new PXOperationCompletedException(messages); // Shows message if you hover over the success checkmark, but you have to hover to see it so not ideal

    }

    public class LocationMessageDisplay : IPXCustomInfo
    {
        public void Complete(PXLongRunStatus status, PXGraph graph)
        {
            if (status == PXLongRunStatus.Completed && graph is CustomerLocationMaint)
            {
                ((CustomerLocationMaint)graph).RowSelected.AddHandler<Location>((sender, e) =>
                {
                    Location location = e.Row as Location;
                    if (location != null)
                    {
                        sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<Location.cResedential>(location, location.CResedential, _message);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        private PXSetPropertyException _message;

        public LocationMessageDisplay(PXSetPropertyException message)
        {
            _message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE - New Approach**

As suggested, this code now calls the LongOperation within the Persist method.

```
protected virtual void Address_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        PX.Objects.CR.Address row = (PX.Objects.CR.Address)e.Row;
        if (row != null)
        {
            Location location = Base.Location.Current;
            LocationExt locationExt = PXCache<Location>.GetExtension<LocationExt>(location);
            locationExt.UsrResidentialValidated = false;
            Base.LocationCurrent.Cache.IsDirty = true; 
        }
    }   

public delegate void PersistDelegate();
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        baseMethod();

        var location = Base.Location.Current;
        PXCache locationCache = Base.LocationCurrent.Cache;
        LocationExt locationExt = PXCache<Location>.GetExtension<LocationExt>(location);

        if (locationExt.UsrResidentialValidated == false)
        {
            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate
            {
                CheckResidential(location);
            });
        }
    }

public void CheckResidential(Location location)
    {
        CustomerLocationMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerLocationMaint>();

        graph.Clear();
        graph.Location.Current = location;

        LocationExt locationExt = location.GetExtension<LocationExt>();
        locationExt.UsrResidentialValidated = true;

        try
        {
          // Residential code using API (this will change the value of the location.CResedential field)
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new PXOperationCompletedWithErrorException(e.Message);
        }

        graph.Location.Update(location);
        graph.Persist();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PXLongOperation is meant to be used in the context of a PXAction callback. This is typically initiated by a menu item or button control, including built-in actions like Save.

**It is an anti-pattern to use it anytime a value changes in the web page. It should be used only when a value is persisted (by Save action) or by another PXAction event handler. You should handle long running validation when user clicks on a button or menu item not when he changes the value.**

For example, the built in Validate Address feature is run only when the user clicks on the Validate Address button and if validated requests are required it is also run in a Persist event called in the context of the Save action to cancel saving if validation fails.

This is done to ensure user expectation that a simple change in a form/grid value field doesn't incur a long validation wait time that would lead the user to believe the web page is unresponsive. When the user clicks on Save or a specific Action button it is deemed more reasonable to expect a longer wait time.

That being said, it is not recommended but possible to wrap your PXLongOperation call in a dummy Action and asynchronously click on the invisible Action button to get the long operation running in the proper context from any event handler (except Initialize):

```
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
      public PXAction<SOOrder> TestLongOperation;

      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test Long Operation", Visible = false, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Invisible)]
      [PXButton]
      public virtual IEnumerable testLongOperation(PXAdapter adapter)
      {
        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate () 
        { 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Base.Document.Ask("Operation Done", MessageButtons.OK);
        });

        return adapter.Get();
      }

      public void SOOrder_OrderDesc_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
      {
        if (!PXLongOperation.Exists(Base.UID))
        {
            // Calling Action Button asynchronously so it can run in the context of a PXAction callback
            Base.Actions["TestLongOperation"].PressButton();
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure wrapping it into PXAction makes it any better. From my point of view, it's better not to have such design

Comment: Totally agree that it is simply not good from a design perspective hence why I described that as an anti-pattern. User should not wait for validation when filling forms/grids so a long operation should not be called from a field/row event handler. From memory the wrapping part is necessary to display the long operation wait indicator and block UI during the operation but that's not helping make the design valid.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make it more clear the suggested solution is to use action callback to trigger long operation.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA thank you. I've added updated my original question with new code that calls the long operation within Persist. Can you verify that this is acceptable?

In particular, there are two things I want to make sure I addressed correctly:

1. I want to still save the record even if long operation fails (e.g. the API is down). 
2. Is it ok to call graph.Persist() within my long operation? Because I change the value of `locationExt.UsrResidentialValidated`, there will not be an infinite loop, but is this the best approach or is there a better way?

Comment: 1. The only way out of a long operation is to throw exceptions. To continue the process make sure to catch all exceptions that occur during the long operation and don't rethrow them. Throwing an exception in that context cancel the long operation.
2. You are creating a new graph to persist those changes which avoid a few issues. Worst that can happen in that context is if the long operation modifies the current documents of the page you will get "Another process has updated the ‘{0}’ record. Your changes will be lost." error message.

Comment: In case you get "Your changes will be lost." I would suggest hooking RowPersisting event instead of Persist. RowPersisting is called just before Persist so you don't even have to call Persist in that context, you only need to change the field value and they will be persisted automatically. There's rarely a need to hook Persist in my experience, most times the logic can be implemented in RowPersisting.

Comment: The recommended design for your specific scenario would be calling SetWarning instead of throwing exception. My reasoning is that errors should prevent persisting, at least that's how the system is designed. Persisting even though some errors occurred is what we consider a Warning scenario. When calling SetWarning the system continues to persist automatically as you want but lets you warn the user that even though his operation has gone through something unexpected has happened.

Comment: For a more in your face warning I would probably use a Ask method to notify the user with a popup message.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA thanks! Can you say more about what you mean by hooking to the RowPersisting event instead of Persist? Do you mean that you'd trigger the long operation from within RowPersisting rather than Persist or that within the long operation you'd use RowPersisting instead of graph.Persist() to save changes back to the graph?

Comment: Once Persist operation is started it's just harder to do anything. For example if you need to save and you do it in persist it will call back persist in an infinite loop. RowPersisting event occurs just before Persist so if you need to cancel or save something you can do it here before Persist is actually started. You don't even have to explicitly call a Save function, simply modify the field values will do because RowPersisting is already called in the context of a Save operation (just before save to be precise).

Comment: To cancel saving throw exception from RowPersisting, to ask confirmation display Ask dialog in RowPersisting. Just avoid Persist unless it's absolutely necessary.